# django models get_or_create integrity error

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model as follows:

```
class Vote(models.Model):

    vote_type = models.BooleanField()
    voted_by =  models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='voted_by')
    voted_for = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='voted_for')
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, null=True, blank=True)
    dtobject  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I want to make sure that a user can vote for an object only once. 
Hence in my views I do the following:

```
    v = Vote.objects.get_or_create(
        vote_type = vtype.get(field_name),
        voted_by_id = request.user.id,
        voted_for_id = mobj.shared_by_id,
        shared_object_id = oid
        )
```

It works fine for the first time, but when there is already an existing vote, i get an integrity error, reasons are obvious. Given the above model and views, what would be a good approach to ensure that the object has not been voted?

Comment: What're the obvious reasons? Could you elaborate them? Also, why `OneToOneField` field here?

Comment: By the way you can just assign objects to foreign keys in constructor, for instance : voted_by = request.user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters in get_or_create comes in two parts : first part is the exact match of the only instance that must exist, and other variable data has to be found in a parameter named "defaults"

See the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create :

```
obj, created = Person.objects.get_or_create(first_name='John', 
    last_name='Lennon', defaults={'birthday': date(1940, 10, 9)})
```

Not sure what is your unique key here, I'll just guess it's voted_by and voted_for, so we have :

```
vote, created = Vote.objects.get_or_create(
    voted_by = request.user,
    vote_type = vtype.get(field_name),
    defaults = dict(
        voted_for_id = mobj.shared_by_id,
        shared_object_id = oid
      )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

`get_or_create` returns a tuple.

```
vote, created = Vote.objects.get_or_create(
    vote_type = vtype.get(field_name),
    voted_by = request.user,
    voted_for_id = mobj.shared_by_id,
    shared_object_id = oid
    )
```

where `created` is `True` or `False` saying if it created or retrieved from database.

Comment: the trouble with this is if a combo of exists, it gives IntegretyError. How to get rid of that?

Comment: Give the traceback messages your are getting.